# Upgrade a diverted package, dpkg error

Tags: apt, upgrade, dpkg

I have installed [ack](http://beyondgrep.com/) (replacement for grep). In debian based systems, since the package name ack already existed (something completely different), the package is called "ack-grep".

The [install instructions](http://beyondgrep.com/install/) mention a way to let the user use the command `ack` as if it was `ack-grep`:

> On Debian-derived distros, ack is packaged as "ack-grep" because
>   "ack" already existed. If you simply install via:
>
> ```
> $ sudo apt-get install ack-grep
> ```
>
> your ack will be called "ack-grep", which is 167% more characters to
>   type per invocation. This is tragic for your poor fingers.
>
> To create a local diversion, renaming ack-grep to ack, first install
>   the ack-grep package as shown above. Then, run:
>
> ```
> $ sudo dpkg-divert --local --divert /usr/bin/ack --rename --add /usr/bin/ack-grep
> ```

So far, so good. Now when I try to upgrade my system, `apt-get upgrade` complains because of the diversion:

```
Unpacking ack-grep (2.12-2) over (2.12-1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/ack-grep_2.12-2_all.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite `/usr/bin/ack', which is the diverted version of `/usr/bin/ack-grep'
```

It's good that dpkg found the diversion, and tried to overwrite `/usr/bin/ack`, but why doesn't it succeed?

I tried to redo the conversion as per the instructions:

```
$ sudo dpkg-divert --local --divert /usr/bin/ack --rename --add /usr/bin/ack-grep 
Leaving 'local diversion of /usr/bin/ack-grep to /usr/bin/ack'
```

, but still upon `apt-get upgrade`, `dpkg` complains.

Is this normal? What should I do to update the diversion? Is there a way to automate it, or make it just work the next time I `apt-get upgrade`?

Comment: It seems that at some point the `ack-grep` package was changed to put the binary to `/usr/bin/ack` instead of `/usr/bin/ack-grep`, which is why you get a conflict. dpkg is apparently not clever enough to overwrite a diversion when the diversion and the conflicting file both belong to the  same package. Or maybe that is considered too dangerous to do automatically. In any case, just remove the diversion, it won't be necessary anymore.

Answer (score 10):

I found a away to fix it, by removing the diversion first:

> dpkg-divert --package ack-grep --local --remove --rename --divert /usr/bin/ack /usr/bin/ack-grep

apt-get upgrade works fine after that.